# pyarrow issue loading in feather module

Tags: python, pyarrow, feather

I have been following the recommendations from  this issue but this hasn't solved my issue
https://github.com/conda-forge/geopandas-feedstock/issues/45

I have tried to create new testing environments, reinstalled all relevant packages and still run into the same error.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/finnlawson/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/lib.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libboost_system.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/finnlawson/opt/anaconda3/lib/libarrow.13.0.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

`conda` list

```
Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2019.03                  py37_0    defaults
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0    defaults
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0    defaults
anaconda                  custom                   py37_1    defaults
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0    defaults
anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_1    defaults
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0    defaults
applaunchservices         0.2.1                      py_0    defaults
appnope                   0.1.0                    py37_0    defaults
appscript                 1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
argh                      0.26.2                   py37_0    defaults
arrow-cpp                 0.13.0           py37h8cfbac2_0    defaults
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py37_0    defaults
astroid                   2.3.3                    py37_0    defaults
astropy                   4.0              py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1    defaults
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0    defaults
autopep8                  1.4.4                      py_0    defaults
babel                     2.8.0                      py_0    defaults
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0    defaults
backports                 1.0                        py_2    defaults
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.1                      py_0    defaults
backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0    defaults
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2    defaults
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1    defaults
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1    defaults
beautifulsoup4            4.8.2                    py37_0    defaults
bitarray                  1.2.0            py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0    defaults
blas                      1.0                         mkl    defaults
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0    defaults
blosc                     1.16.3               hd9629dc_0    defaults
bokeh                     1.4.0                    py37_0    defaults
boost-cpp                 1.67.0               h1de35cc_4    defaults
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0    defaults
bottleneck                1.3.1            py37h1d22016_0    defaults
brotli                    1.0.7                h0a44026_0    defaults
bzip2                     1.0.8                h1de35cc_0    defaults
ca-certificates           2019.11.27                    0    defaults
certifi                   2019.11.28               py37_0    defaults
cffi                      1.13.2           py37hb5b8e2f_0    defaults
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003    defaults
click                     7.0                      py37_0    defaults
cloudpickle               1.2.2                      py_0    defaults
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1    defaults
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0    defaults
conda                     4.8.1                    py37_0    defaults
conda-build               3.18.11                  py37_0    defaults
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1    defaults
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1    defaults
contextlib2               0.6.0.post1                py_0    defaults
cryptography              2.8              py37ha12b0ac_0    defaults
curl                      7.67.0               ha441bb4_0    defaults
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0    defaults
cython                    0.29.14          py37h0a44026_0    defaults
cytoolz                   0.10.1           py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
dask                      2.9.1                      py_0    defaults
dask-core                 2.9.1                      py_0    defaults
dbus                      1.13.12              h90a0687_0    defaults
decorator                 4.4.1                      py_0    defaults
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0    defaults
diff-match-patch          20181111                   py_0    defaults
distributed               2.9.1                      py_0    defaults
docutils                  0.15.2                   py37_0    defaults
double-conversion         3.1.5                haf313ee_1    defaults
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0    defaults
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0    defaults
expat                     2.2.6                h0a44026_0    defaults
ez-setup                  0.9                      pypi_0    pypi
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
feather-format            0.4.0                   py_1003    conda-forge
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0    defaults
flake8                    3.7.9                    py37_0    defaults
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0    defaults
freetype                  2.9.1                hb4e5f40_0    defaults
fsspec                    0.6.2                      py_0    defaults
future                    0.18.2                   py37_0    defaults
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h7520d66_0    defaults
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h15daf44_3    defaults
gevent                    1.4.0            py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
gflags                    2.2.2                h0a44026_0    defaults
glib                      2.63.1               hd977a24_0    defaults
glob2                     0.7                        py_0    defaults
glog                      0.4.0                h0a44026_0    defaults
gmp                       6.1.2                hb37e062_1    defaults
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py37h6ef4df4_2    defaults
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
h5py                      2.9.0            py37h3134771_0    defaults
hdf5                      1.10.4               hfa1e0ec_0    defaults
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0    defaults
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0    defaults
hypothesis                4.54.2                   py37_0    defaults
icu                       58.2                 h4b95b61_1    defaults
idna                      2.8                      py37_0    defaults
imageio                   2.6.1                    py37_0    defaults
imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0    defaults
importlib_metadata        1.3.0                    py37_0    defaults
intel-openmp              2019.4                      233    defaults
intervaltree              3.0.2                      py_0    defaults
ipykernel                 5.1.3            py37h39e3cac_0    defaults
ipython                   7.11.1           py37h39e3cac_0    defaults
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0    defaults
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0    defaults
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0    defaults
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0    defaults
jbig                      2.1                  h4d881f8_0    defaults
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0    defaults
jedi                      0.14.1                   py37_0    defaults
jinja2                    2.10.3                     py_0    defaults
joblib                    0.14.1                     py_0    defaults
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2    defaults
json5                     0.8.5                      py_0    defaults
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py37_0    defaults
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7    defaults
jupyter_client            5.3.4                    py37_0    defaults
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0    defaults
jupyter_core              4.6.1                    py37_0    defaults
jupyterlab                1.2.4              pyhf63ae98_0    defaults
jupyterlab_server         1.0.6                      py_0    defaults
keyring                   20.0.0                   py37_0    defaults
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37h0a44026_0    defaults
krb5                      1.16.4               hddcf347_0    defaults
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
libarchive                3.3.3                h786848e_5    defaults
libboost                  1.67.0               hebc422b_4    defaults
libcurl                   7.67.0               h051b688_0    defaults
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1    defaults
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1    defaults
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0    defaults
libevent                  2.1.8                ha12b0ac_0    defaults
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4    defaults
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2    defaults
libiconv                  1.15                 hdd342a3_7    defaults
liblief                   0.9.0                h2a1bed3_2    defaults
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0    defaults
libprotobuf               3.6.0                hd9629dc_0    defaults
libsodium                 1.0.16               h3efe00b_0    defaults
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h0a44026_0    defaults
libssh2                   1.8.2                ha12b0ac_0    defaults
libtiff                   4.1.0                hcb84e12_0    defaults
libxml2                   2.9.9                hf6e021a_1    defaults
libxslt                   1.1.33               h33a18ac_0    defaults
llvm-openmp               4.0.1                hcfea43d_1    defaults
llvmlite                  0.30.0           py37h98b8051_0    defaults
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1    defaults
lxml                      4.4.2            py37hef8c89e_0    defaults
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h1de35cc_0    defaults
lzo                       2.10                 h362108e_2    defaults
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
matplotlib                3.1.1            py37h54f8f79_0    defaults
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1    defaults
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
mkl                       2019.4                      233    defaults
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hfbe908c_0    defaults
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py37h5e564d8_0    defaults
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37ha771720_0    defaults
mock                      3.0.5                    py37_0    defaults
more-itertools            8.0.2                      py_0    defaults
mpc                       1.1.0                h6ef4df4_1    defaults
mpfr                      4.0.1                h3018a27_3    defaults
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0    defaults
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py37h04f5b5a_1    defaults
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0    defaults
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0    defaults
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0    defaults
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0    defaults
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1    defaults
networkx                  2.4                        py_0    defaults
nltk                      3.4.5                    py37_0    defaults
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2    defaults
notebook                  6.0.2                    py37_0    defaults
numba                     0.46.0           py37h6440ff4_0    defaults
numexpr                   2.7.0            py37h7413580_0    defaults
numpy                     1.17.4           py37h890c691_0    defaults
numpy-base                1.17.4           py37h6575580_0    defaults
numpydoc                  0.9.2                      py_0    defaults
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0    defaults
openpyxl                  3.0.2                      py_0    defaults
openssl                   1.1.1d               h1de35cc_3    defaults
packaging                 20.0                       py_0    defaults
pandas                    0.25.3           py37h0a44026_0    defaults
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0    defaults
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1    defaults
parso                     0.5.2                      py_0    defaults
partd                     1.1.0                      py_0    defaults
path                      13.1.0                   py37_0    defaults
path.py                   12.4.0                        0    defaults
pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py37_0    defaults
pathtools                 0.1.2                      py_1    defaults
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0    defaults
pcre                      8.43                 h0a44026_0    defaults
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0    defaults
pexpect                   4.7.0                    py37_0    defaults
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0    defaults
pillow                    7.0.0            py37h4655f20_0    defaults
pip                       19.3.1                   py37_0    defaults
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0    defaults
pluggy                    0.13.1                   py37_0    defaults
ply                       3.11                     py37_0    defaults
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0    defaults
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                    py37_0    defaults
psutil                    5.6.7            py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0    defaults
pulp                      2.0                      pypi_0    pypi
py                        1.8.1                      py_0    defaults
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37h1413db1_2    defaults
pyarrow                   0.13.0           py37h0a44026_0    defaults
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0    defaults
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0    defaults
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37h1de35cc_9    defaults
pycurl                    7.43.0.3         py37ha12b0ac_0    defaults
pydocstyle                4.0.1                      py_0    defaults
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0    defaults
pygments                  2.5.2                      py_0    defaults
pylint                    2.4.4                    py37_0    defaults
pyodbc                    4.0.27           py37h0a44026_0    defaults
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py37_0    defaults
pyparsing                 2.4.6                      py_0    defaults
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h655552a_2    defaults
pyrsistent                0.15.6           py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0    defaults
pytables                  3.6.1            py37h5bccee9_0    defaults
pytest                    5.3.2                    py37_0    defaults
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0    defaults
pytest-astropy            0.7.0                      py_0    defaults
pytest-astropy-header     0.1.1                      py_0    defaults
pytest-doctestplus        0.5.0                      py_0    defaults
pytest-openfiles          0.4.0                      py_0    defaults
pytest-remotedata         0.3.2                    py37_0    defaults
python                    3.7.6                h359304d_2    defaults
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    defaults
python-jsonrpc-server     0.3.2                      py_0    defaults
python-language-server    0.31.2                   py37_0    defaults
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_13    defaults
python.app                2                        py37_9    defaults
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0    defaults
pywavelets                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
pyyaml                    5.2              py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
pyzmq                     18.1.0           py37h0a44026_0    defaults
qdarkstyle                2.7                        py_0    defaults
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1    defaults
qtawesome                 0.6.0                      py_0    defaults
qtconsole                 4.6.0                      py_1    defaults
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0    defaults
re2                       2019.08.01           h0a44026_0    defaults
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5    defaults
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_1    defaults
ripgrep                   11.0.2               he32d670_0    defaults
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0    defaults
rtree                     0.8.3                    py37_0    defaults
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
scikit-image              0.15.0           py37h0a44026_0    defaults
scikit-learn              0.22.1           py37h27c97d8_0    defaults
scipy                     1.3.1            py37h1410ff5_0    defaults
seaborn                   0.9.0              pyh91ea838_1    defaults
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0    defaults
setuptools                42.0.2                   pypi_0    pypi
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2    defaults
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0    defaults
sip                       4.19.8           py37h0a44026_0    defaults
six                       1.13.0                   py37_0    defaults
snappy                    1.1.7                he62c110_3    defaults
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0    defaults
sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py37_0    defaults
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0    defaults
soupsieve                 1.9.5                    py37_0    defaults
sphinx                    2.3.1                      py_0    defaults
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1    defaults
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0    defaults
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0    defaults
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0    defaults
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0    defaults
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0    defaults
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0    defaults
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.2                      py_0    defaults
spyder                    4.0.1                    py37_0    defaults
spyder-kernels            1.8.1                    py37_0    defaults
sqlalchemy                1.3.12           py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
sqlite                    3.30.1               ha441bb4_0    defaults
statsmodels               0.10.1           py37h1d22016_0    defaults
sympy                     1.5.1                    py37_0    defaults
tbb                       2019.8               h04f5b5a_0    defaults
tblib                     1.6.0                      py_0    defaults
terminado                 0.8.3                    py37_0    defaults
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0    defaults
thrift-cpp                0.11.0               hd79cdb6_3    defaults
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0    defaults
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0    defaults
tornado                   6.0.3            py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
tqdm                      4.41.1                     py_0    defaults
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0    defaults
ujson                     1.35             py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0    defaults
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h1de35cc_0    defaults
urllib3                   1.25.7                   py37_0    defaults
watchdog                  0.9.0                    py37_1    defaults
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0    defaults
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1    defaults
werkzeug                  0.16.0                     py_0    defaults
wheel                     0.33.6                   py37_0    defaults
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0    defaults
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37h1de35cc_0    defaults
wurlitzer                 2.0.0                    py37_0    defaults
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0    defaults
xlsxwriter                1.2.7                      py_0    defaults
xlwings                   0.17.0                   py37_0    defaults
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0    defaults
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4    defaults
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2    defaults
yapf                      0.28.0                     py_0    defaults
zeromq                    4.3.1                h0a44026_3    defaults
zict                      1.0.0                      py_0    defaults
zipp                      0.6.0                      py_0    defaults
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3    defaults
zstd                      1.3.7                h5bba6e5_0    defaults
```

Comment: Python version 3.7.6

Comment: pip install image

Comment: Still returning same error message

Comment: Please open an issue at https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues